# disable or hide button in another application

Tags: c#, api

I'm trying to disable or hide a button in another application

I get the hndl of button but when I call `SendMessage`

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam,
   bool lParam);

bool x = SendMessage(hndl, TB_HIDEBUTTON, 0, false);
```

nothing happens and x always returns false.  I have also tried `TB_DELETEBUTTON`

Comment: Just to mention something here. Unless the program expresses an API to disable or hide that button, it's generally a **very bad idea** to mess with it. If you're lucky, the program will work okay, but if you're unlucky, it could crash... or worse.

Answer (score 3):

You're sending the wrong message. Get a handle to the button, and call `EnableWindow(hndl, FALSE);` instead (or if you want to hide it, try `ShowWindow(hndl, SW_HIDE);`).

Comment: What did you do to make it work? If my suggestion is correct, then can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

TB_HIDEBUTTON is a window message that used to hide the button in a toolbar.
If you want to do this, there is something wrong with your code, you must provide the button identifer as the third parameter of SendMessage, go to [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787358%28VS.85%29.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for Internet Explorer 11 (called from dll injected into iexplore):

```
HWND Suchleiste = FindWindowEx(GetActiveWindow(), NULL, NULL, "Navigationsleiste"); // WorkerW

Suchleiste = FindWindowEx(Suchleiste, NULL, "ReBarWindow32", NULL);

AddressbarRight = FindWindowEx(Suchleiste, NULL, "ControlBandClass", NULL);

AddressbarRight = FindWindowEx(AddressbarRight, NULL, "ToolbarWindow32", NULL);

TBBUTTON tButton;

SendMessage(AddressbarRight, TB_GETBUTTON, 0, (LPARAM)&tButton); // 0 == Home button

SendMessage(AddressbarRight, TB_HIDEBUTTON, tButton.idCommand, (LPARAM)MAKELONG(TRUE, 0)); // idCommand == 1

//SendMessage(AddressbarRight, TB_ENABLEBUTTON, tButton.idCommand, (LPARAM)MAKELONG(FALSE, 0)); // makes it inactive
```

Everybody says to use "DestroyWindow" or "EnableWindow" or whatever. These buttons are not windows, if I interpret "inspect" and "spyxx_amd64" output correctly.

Events:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/toolbar-control-reference

Functions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl

The ImageList_ functions don't work correctly though. Like I call "ImageList_Remove":

```
HIMAGELIST mlist=(HIMAGELIST)::SendMessage(AddressbarRight, TB_GETIMAGELIST, 0, 0);

ImageList_Remove(mlist, 0);
```

but the button is still visible when I hover over it, looks broken though. But the event:

```
SendMessage(AddressbarRight, TB_DELETEBUTTON, 0, 0);
```

removes the icon completely. forever. Besides, if you use events, you don't need to link to "comctl32".

Beware when deleting buttons! The index decreases, so you delete index 0, index 1 takes its index (becoming 0). So when deleting several buttons, go backwards, starting with the highest index.